# How to use Next.js and Stratpi to list products by category？

Tags: javascript

I used nextjs and strategy to learn the course and wrote a product display page. I want the product to be displayed on the homepage by product category and can control the number of products displayed, such as product cameras, phones, headphones, etc
[image]

[image]

productCard.js

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";

const ProductCard = ({ data: { attributes: p, id } }) => {
    return (
        <div className="group rounded-md shadow-xl">
            <Link href={`/product/${p.slug}`}>
                <div className="transform overflow-hidden cursor-pointer">
                    <Image
                        className="w-full h-full object-cover group-hover:scale-110 duration-500"
                        src={p.thumbnail?.data?.attributes.url || "/p1.png"}
                        width={640}
                        height={640}
                        alt={p.name}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="p-4 text-black/[0.9]">
                    <h2 className="text-sm md:text-md lg:text-lg font-medium">
                        {p.name.length > 10 ? `${p.name.slice(10, 60)}` : p.name}
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Home.js

```
import HeroBanner from "@/components/HeroBanner";
import ProductCard from "@/components/ProductCard";
import Wrapper from "@/components/Wrapper";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "@/utils/api";

export default function Home({ products }) {
    return (
        <>
            <main>
                <Wrapper>
                    <HeroBanner />
                    {/* products grid start */}
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-2 md:gap-3 lg:gap-4 my-14  md:px-0">
                        {products?.data?.map((product) => (
                            <ProductCard
                                key={product?.id}
                                data={product}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    {/* products grid end */}
                </Wrapper>
                <div className="min-h-screen hidden md:flex justify-center items-center bg-sea1 bg-fixed bg-cover bg-no-repeat w-[1920px] h-[260px] md:h-[480px] "></div>
                <div className="container mx-auto  flex flex-col justify-center  bg-white p-10">
                    <span className="py-4">
                        Mihaqi Textile adopts a "5-s management" approach, which not only
                        continuously strengthens the quality of its excellent team, but also
                        continuously improves the quality of the company's on-site
                        environment to maintain the ability to deliver the highest quality
                        products and services to customers at all times. Our professional
                        team is dedicated to producing and providing the highest quality
                        environmentally friendly textiles to renowned curtain brands around
                        the world.
                    </span>
                    <hr className="mt-8" />
                    <span className="flex justify-center">
                        <img
                            src="/icon/certifications.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div className="min-h-screen hidden md:flex justify-center items-center bg-sea2 bg-fixed bg-cover bg-no-repeat w-[1920px] h-[260px] md:h-[480px] "></div>
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const products = await fetchDataFromApi("/api/products?populate=*");

    return {
        props: { products },
    };
}
```

I want the homepage to display the product categories of each category as shown in the picture. Currently, the product categories can be implemented, but I don't know the method of displaying categories on the homepage.

category/slug.js

```
import ProductCard from "@/components/ProductCard";
import Wrapper from "@/components/Wrapper";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "@/utils/api";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const maxResult = 8;

const Category = ({ category, products, slug }) => {
    const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(1);
    const { query } = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        setPageIndex(1);
    }, [query]);
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
        `/api/products?populate=*&[filters][category][slug][$eq]=${slug}&pagination[page]=${pageIndex}&pagination[pageSize]=${maxResult}`,
        fetchDataFromApi,
        {
            fallbackData: products,
        },
    );
    return (
        <div className="w-full md:py-20">
            <Wrapper>
                <div className="text-center max-w-[800px] mx-auto mt-8 md:mt-0">
                    <div className="text-[28px] md:text-[34px] mb-5">
                        {category?.data?.[0]?.attributes?.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-5 my-14 px-5 md:px-0">
                    {data?.data?.map((product) => (
                        <ProductCard
                            key={product?.id}
                            data={product}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
                {/* PAGINATION BUTTONS START */}
                {data?.meta?.pagination?.total > maxResult && (
                    <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center my-16 md:my-0">
                        <button
                            className={`rounded py-2 px-4 bg-black text-white disabled:bg-gray-200 disabled:text-gray-500`}
                            disabled={pageIndex === 1}
                            onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex - 1)}
                        >
                            Previous
                        </button>

                        <span className="font-bold">{`${pageIndex} of ${
                            data && data.meta.pagination.pageCount
                        }`}</span>

                        <button
                            className={`rounded py-2 px-4 bg-black text-white disabled:bg-gray-200 disabled:text-gray-500`}
                            disabled={pageIndex === (data && data.meta.pagination.pageCount)}
                            onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex + 1)}
                        >
                            Next
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
                {/* PAGINATION BUTTONS END */}
                {isLoading && (
                    <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full bg-white/[0.5] flex flex-col gap-5 justify-center items-center">
                        <span className="text-2xl">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Category;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const category = await fetchDataFromApi("/api/categories?populate=*");
    const paths = category.data.map((c) => ({
        params: {
            slug: c.attributes.slug,
        },
    }));

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
    const category = await fetchDataFromApi(
        `/api/categories?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}`,
    );
    const products = await fetchDataFromApi(
        `/api/products?populate=*&[filters][category][slug][$eq]=${slug}&pagination[page]=2&pagination[pageSize]=${maxResult}`,
    );

    return {
        props: {
            category,
            products,
            slug,
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: can you share some example which you have tried?

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the content of the question again. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use nested maps here.
I am assuming that the products model has a relationship with the categories model.
It would look something like this

```
{categories.data.map(c => <>
  // display category name here
  {products.data.filter(p => p.category === c._id).map(p => <>
    // display product card here
  </>)}
</>)}
```

This might be what you are looking for.

PS: You can either call the API once and filter that data like the above example or call it separately for each component, increasing the number of API calls and database queries.

Comment: Thank you for your patient guidance. I am a novice and will try to follow your method.